# How to hit through HTTP a container created from another container mounted with /var/run/docker.sock?

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

This is a for a CI server setup. The CI doesn't have tools like `node` installed, **only Docker**. So I have to run my tests inside a container.

This container will, in turn, create a second container to run the integration tests against.

The first container has mounted the `/var/run/docker.sock` so that it can create a second container. **Both containers live side by side**.

My build steps are the following:

1. Clone source code
2. Build docker image and tag it `my-app`
3. Run unit tests `docker run ..... my-app yarn test`
4. Run integration tests, **which fire up a container**. `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ..... my-app yarn test:integration`

The problem is in the integration tests:

In summary, the first container calls `yarn:integration` which fires up the 2nd container running the app on port 3001, and then runs the tests against the 2nd container. Finally, it stops the second container.

The problem is that my integration tests in the first container attempt to hit the 2nd container through `localhost:3001`, but `localhost` is not the right host to the second container.

How can I access the second container from the first one, considering they are side by side (and not one within the other)?

Comment: When you say your first container calls `yarn:integration` and fires up the second container, is the second container running inside the first?

Comment: No, it's through the `/var/run/docker.sock`. I'll update it

Comment: I've updated my question to better clarify my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` within the container doesn't point to the host machine, it points to the container itself. If you want to reach another container you need to use that **container's actual IP** which can be discovered by `docker inspect <CONTAINER ID>` and **the internal port** (i.e. **not** the one mapped to your host).

Alternatively, you can create a [user-defined network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge) and [connect](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-a-user-defined-bridge) your containers to it. Then you will be able to use container names as hostnames, e.g. `my-app:3001`. Note that container name is the one specified by `--name` parameter of `docker run`. Also you need to use the container's internal port and **not** the one published with `-p` parameter.

Comment: I updated my question to specify the second container is not inside the first one, but side-by-side through the `/var/run/docker.sock` file

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco, yes, my answer applies to that exact situation. I have no idea why is it downvoted.

Comment: Ok, sounds like from the first container, after launching the second container I'd run docker inspect on the container ID,  pick the IP and inject it to my integration tests. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco, either that or you can use a user-defined network. Please see my updated answer.